# Can Oauth2 with Password workflow implement Wso2 EmailOTP and SMSOTP Authenticator

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am using Wso2 Oauth2 password grant for authenticating the user in my application. I need to implement two factor authentication using sms and email in my existing workflow. I have gone through the  Wso2 documentation  found authenticator for Email and SMS.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/ISCONNECTORS/Configuring+EmailOTP+Authenticator
https://docs.wso2.com/display/ISCONNECTORS/SMSOTP+Authenticator

But these documentation deals with SAML.

Is there any documentation for Oauth2 workflow or How it can be achieved ?

Need help on this
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have configured a service provider with **OAuth/OpenID Connect Configuration** type in WSO2 Identity Server. You need to do the **Local & Outbound Authentication Configuration** in this OAuth Service Provider. Hit edit for that SP and expand **Local & Outbound Authentication Configuration**. Click on **Advanced Configuration** and do necessary configuration there.
Refer https://docs.wso2.com/display/ISCONNECTORS/Configuring+EmailOTP+Authenticator and follow the steps starting from **Step 9** in **Configuring the Service Provider** section.